# Tool to Show Real Time Disk Usage in Windows (XP, Vista)

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, disk-space-utilization

If you run Task Manager (or Process Explorer) and minimise it, it puts an icon in the icon tray which shows current processor usage as a little bar graph.

I would like to find a similar tool which will show me current disk activity in a similar way.
Even better... a tool which shows me a graph of recent disk activity.
Even better than that ... showing it by application.

I'm mainly going to use this on Windows XP, but a tool which works for Vista would be useful too.

I know that some of the Sysinternals tools almost show me this, but none of them is quite there.

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can view the IO usage in the system tray using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) by enabling "Options->I/O History Tray Icon".

Hover over the icon, and it will tell you which app is using the most IO right now.

Comment: nice.  I had to go and get the latest version, which is fab.  top tip!

Answer (score 3):

Vista has this capability in Reliability and Performance monitor.  Open it and expand the Disk section and you'll see disk stats per process.

Answer (score 1):

Perfmon's Physical Disk and Logical Disk counters work great.